# How to run the sql script from the EER designed on MySQL Workbench to MySQL Server (Ubuntu)

Tags: mysql, sql, mysql-workbench, forward, forward-engineer

I have generated this script from MySQL WorkBench but when i try to run it in my MySQL Server, i get the following error:
'17:28:11   DROP SCHEMA IF EXISTS `MYA_Database_Schema` Error Code: 1044. Access denied for user ''@'localhost' to database 'MYA_Database_Schema'   0.000 sec'

The first 2 tables are created without any issues, but when it comes to BMCDetail, i keep getting errors.
Any help is appreciated since i am designing database for a new project and i need to get this database schema on the server as soon as possible. Any help would be great, even if you point me in the right direction.

Operating system    Ubuntu Linux 12.04
MySQL version 5.5.22

I tried to replicate this on a local xampp server that i installed through phpmyadmin and still similar issue.

```
'SET @OLD_UNIQUE_CHECKS=@@UNIQUE_CHECKS, UNIQUE_CHECKS=0;
SET @OLD_FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=@@FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS, FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=0;
SET @OLD_SQL_MODE=@@SQL_MODE, SQL_MODE='TRADITIONAL,ALLOW_INVALID_DATES';

DROP SCHEMA IF EXISTS `MYA_Database_Schema` ;
CREATE SCHEMA IF NOT EXISTS `MYA_Database_Schema` DEFAULT CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE     utf8_general_ci ;
SHOW WARNINGS;
USE `MYA_Database_Schema` ;
```

---

-- Table `BMCSupervisor`

---

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `BMCSupervisor` ;

SHOW WARNINGS;
CREATE  TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `BMCSupervisor` (
  `idBMCSupervisor` INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT ,
  `SupervisorName` VARCHAR(30) NULL ,
  `EmployeeCode` INT NULL ,
   `PhoneNumber` INT NULL ,
  `EmailID` VARCHAR(100) NULL ,
  `BMCSupervisorID` VARCHAR(5) NOT NULL ,
  PRIMARY KEY (`idBMCSupervisor`, `BMCSupervisorID`) )
ENGINE = InnoDB;

SHOW WARNINGS;
```

---

-- Table `BMCSupplierEnrolManager`

---

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `BMCSupplierEnrolManager` ;

SHOW WARNINGS;
CREATE  TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `BMCSupplierEnrolManager` (
  `idBMCSupplierEnrolManager` INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT ,
  `Name` VARCHAR(25) NULL ,
  `EmployeeCode` INT NULL ,
  `PhoneNumber` INT NULL ,
  `EmailID` VARCHAR(100) NULL ,
  `SupplierEnrolManagerID` INT NOT NULL ,
  PRIMARY KEY (`idBMCSupplierEnrolManager`, `SupplierEnrolManagerID`) )
ENGINE = InnoDB;

 SHOW WARNINGS;
```

---

-- Table `BMCDetail`

---

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `BMCDetail` ;

SHOW WARNINGS;
CREATE  TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `BMCDetail` (
  `idBMCDetail` INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT ,
  `BMCCode` VARCHAR(5) NOT NULL ,
  `BMCName` VARCHAR(10) NULL ,
  `State` VARCHAR(25) NOT NULL ,
  `District` VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL ,
  `Block` VARCHAR(15) NULL ,
  `Taluk` VARCHAR(15) NULL ,
  `Village` VARCHAR(20) NULL ,
  `BMCCapacity` DECIMAL(10,2) NULL ,
  `DateOfCommissioning` DATE NULL ,
  `SupervisorID` VARCHAR(5) NOT NULL ,
  `SupplierEnrolManagerID` INT NOT NULL ,
  PRIMARY KEY (`idBMCDetail`, `BMCCode`, `State`, `District`) ,
  CONSTRAINT `SupervisorID`
    FOREIGN KEY (`SupervisorID` )
    REFERENCES `BMCSupervisor` (`BMCSupervisorID` )
    ON DELETE NO ACTION
    ON UPDATE NO ACTION,
  CONSTRAINT `SupplierEnrolManagerID`
    FOREIGN KEY (`SupplierEnrolManagerID` )
    REFERENCES `BMCSupplierEnrolManager` (`SupplierEnrolManagerID` )
    ON DELETE NO ACTION
    ON UPDATE NO ACTION)
ENGINE = InnoDB;'
```

Comment: What users do you have defined on your MySqlDb, and which user do you think you are connecting as ?

Comment: Hi Jones,I am connecting using a test user called kelvin with all privileges granted to it. I  have configured this in MySQL Workbench as well.

Comment: Have tried to change the user with giving the new user full privileges and still coming up with the same error.

Comment: Would you not expect the user to be 'kelvin'@'localhost', or 'kelvin'@'%' ?